# How to get Distinct Value in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table `approval` like below..

| m_requisition_id | ad_wf_activity_id | bpname | designation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1014546 | 1014546 | Abul Kalam Azad | Asst. Manager |
| 1014546 | 1225097 | Md. Hasan Zahir | Plant Manager |
| 1014546 | 1229239 | Md. Hasan Zahir | Plant Manager |
| 1014546 | 1229240 | Sayela Alam | Sr. Manager |
| 1014546 | 1229241 | Md. Hasan Zahir | Plant Manager |
| 1014546 | 1229242 | Sayela Alam | Sr. Manager |

Now i need `bpname` column's distinct value based on `ad_wf_activity_id` column's maximum number like below.

| m_requisition_id | ad_wf_activity_id | bpname | designation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1014546 | 1014546 | Abul Kalam Azad | Asst. Manager |
| 1014546 | 1229241 | Md. Hasan Zahir | Plant Manager |
| 1014546 | 1229242 | Sayela Alam | Sr. Manager |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **max()** function instead of **distinct** on like below

```
select m_requisition_id, max(ad_wf_activity_id), bpname, designation
from approval
GROUP BY m_requisition_id, bpname, designation
```

Lets try here-
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=73f15e1ed96f1308a5984a91b1df91e2

Answer (score 1):

That would be `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m_requisition_id, bpname, designation)
       m_requisition_id, bpname, designation
FROM atable
ORDER BY m_requisition_id, bpname, designation, ad_wf_activity_id DESC;
```

Your data model is not normalized, you you are prone to problems caused by slightly different spellings.